# which mogodb drive appropriate file?

Tags: php, mongodb, wampserver

i would like to determined the appropriate file that matches my PHP version
i am using windows , wampserver

```
PHP Version 7.0.0
PHP API 20151012
PHP Extension   20151012
Zend Extension  320151012
Zend Extension Build    API320151012,TS,VC14
PHP Extension Build API20151012,TS,VC14
Thread Safety   enabled
```

which dll can i use from [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use any driver from the list you have linked because these are legacy drivers that do not work with PHP 7. You can find installation guide for new driver for Windows in the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php).